# Geometrical problem in Newton's "Principia".

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let VQPA be the circumference
of the circle, S the given
point toward which the force
tends as to its center, P the body
revolving in the circumference, Q
the place to which it will move
next, and PRZ the tangent of
the circle at the previous place.
Through point S draw chord PV;
and when the diameter VA of
the circle has been drawn, join
AP; and to SP drop perpendicular
QT, which when produced meets the tangent PR at Z; and finally through
point Q draw LR parallel to SP and meeting both the circle at L and the
tangent PZ at R. Then because the triangles ZQR, ZTP, and VPA are
similar, $RP^2$ (that is, QR x RL) will be to $QT^2$ as $AV^2$ to $PV^2$.[image]

**My question is how can we prove the similarity of triangles  ZQR, ZTP, and VPA?**

Comment: $\triangle ZQR\sim \triangle ZTP$ because $\overline{QR}\parallel\overline{TP}$. For the other similarity, first note that $\angle VPA$ is a right angle (via [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem)). Also, if we introduce $O$ as the center of the circle (aka, the midpoint of $\overline{VA}$), we can do a little angle-chasing to show
$$\angle ZPT=90^\circ−\angle OPT=\angle OPA = \angle A$$ Thus, $\triangle ZTP\sim\triangle VPA$ by Angle-Angle Similarity.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting the comment of @Blue on the similarity of triangles $ZQR$ and $ZTP$, then without further construction, since $PZ$ is tangent at $P$, in right triangles $ZTP$ and $VPA$, $\angle ZPT=\angle VAP$ (Euclid, *Elements III, 32*). Therefore$$\triangle ZTP\sim\triangle VPA$$